# python web scraping - setting date

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a python code for scraping this web page: http://www.arpa.umbria.it/monitoraggi/aria/Default.aspx

I'd like to run a script to get a table for each day in a particular time lapse (e.g. from 1-1-2019 to 31-12-22019). I don't have a particular problem to do it for a current data showed as default in the web page. Unfortunately I'm not able to set different dates than the current in the site. For example in my code I've asked the data "19/12/2019" but I get the current data in web page.

This is my code:

```
import urllib.request as urlRequest
import urllib.parse as urlParse

url = 'http://www.arpa.umbria.it/monitoraggi/aria/Default.aspx'
values={"ctl00$Content$txtData":"19/12/2019"}
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"}
params = urlParse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8")
targetUrl = urlRequest.Request(url=url, data=params, headers=headers)
x  = urlRequest.urlopen(targetUrl)
respone = x.read()
print(respone)
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you want so copy all the data included in tables you can `lxml.html` library like so

```
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib.request as urlRequest
import urllib.parse as urlParse

url = 'http://www.arpa.umbria.it/monitoraggi/aria/Default.aspx'
values={"ctl00$Content$txtData":"19/12/2019"}
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"}
params = urlParse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8")
targetUrl = urlRequest.Request(url=url, data=params, headers=headers)
x  = urlRequest.urlopen(targetUrl)
respone = x.read()

doc = lh.fromstring(respone)
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')
table=[]
for i, elem in enumerate(tr_elements):
    row = []
    for j, t in enumerate(elem):
        name=t.text_content()
        row.append(name)
    table.append(row)

max_row_len = max(len(r) for r in table)
table = [r + [None]*(max_row_len-len(r)) for r in table]
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
```

and then using that pandas dataframe you can drop all rows and columns that are useless

```
df = df.drop(index=[0, 1, 16, 17, 27, 28, 31, 32], columns=[0])
```

end result

[image: End result]

And finally you can wrap that code in a function and call it for each date.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the problem is that I get always the table related the "default" date in the web page, (today is as for 30/04/2020), even if I ask, e.g., 19/12/2019, or any different date. Thanks!